nrf24l01 hardware not working with esp32-s3
I am trying to test my nrf21l01 + pa/lna pinout with my esp32-s3-wroom1 in thonny (I installed the nrf24l01 package from thonny) and I am getting this error:
MPY: soft reboot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 19, in <module>
  File "/lib/nrf24l01.py", line 78, in __init__
OSError: nRF24L01+ Hardware not responding

This is the code I am using:
from machine import Pin, SPI
from nrf24l01 import NRF24L01

# SPI setup
spi = SPI(2, baudrate=1000000, polarity=0, phase=0, sck=Pin(14), mosi=Pin(13), miso=Pin(12))
csn = Pin(15, Pin.OUT)
ce = Pin(16, Pin.OUT)

# Initialize NRF24L01
try:
     nrf = NRF24L01(spi, csn, ce)
     print("NRF24L01 initialized successfully!")
 except OSError as e:
     print("Error initializing NRF24L01:", e)


SPI(2, baudrate=1000000, polarity=0, phase=0, firstbit=SPI.MSB, sck=Pin(14), mosi=Pin(13), miso=Pin(12)) (you are missing firstbit, it could be SPI.MSB or SPI.LSB) . See documentation.
